# BeforeRefresh and AfterRefresh not working

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to trigger the BeforeRefresh and AfterRefresh events with the following code:

Under a class module named clsQuery, I have:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
If Success Then MsgBox "Query has been refreshed."
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
If MsgBox("Refresh query?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Then under Modules, I have:

```
Option Explicit
Dim colQueries As New Collection

Sub InitializeQueries()

Dim clsQ As clsQuery
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim QT As QueryTable

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each QT In WS.QueryTables
Set clsQ = New clsQuery
Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
colQueries.Add clsQ
Next QT
Next WS
MsgBox ("Works")

End Sub
```

And lastly under Microsoft Excel Objects, I have in a tab named ThisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit
Dim colQueries As New Collection

Sub InitializeQueries()

Dim clsQ As clsQuery
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim QT As QueryTable

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each QT In WS.QueryTables
Set clsQ = New clsQuery
Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
colQueries.Add clsQ
Next QT
Next WS
MsgBox ("Works")

End Sub
```

So when I first open the excel file, the messagebox comes up and says "Works". However, when I try to refresh the data, the message boxes for before refresh and after refresh doesn't come up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you are recreating colQueries, this needs to be created once public, and added to.  I'd have the collection public in a module, then on sheet change, create new collection and run your Initialise routine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you.  Not too different, but a single collection added to.

[image]